# Dynamically update a count querying django ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Im developing a site in django with two models: Match, Month

I want to Update a query in Match model so it will update a specific query in Month model aswell.

**models.py:**

```py
from django.db import models


class Month(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    matches_count = models.IntegerField()

class Match(models.Model):
    first_team = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    second_team = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    in_month = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

I Have made those queries in my **views.py** file:

```
_query_one = Month(name = 'January',matches_count = 0)
_query_one.save()

_query_two = Month(name = 'February',matches_count = 0)
_query_two.save()

_query_three = Match(first_team = 'LA',second_team = 'NYC', in_month = 'March')
_query_three.save()

_query_four = Match(first_team = 'SF',second_team = 'LV', in_month = 'February')
_query_four.save()
```

My goal is to update the new 'matches_count' value of February month from 0 to 1.

I've searched for a smarter way to do that except of just running this snippet right after the query:

```py
_query_to_update = Month.objects.get(name = 'February')
_query_to_update.matches_count = 1
_query_to_update.update()
```

I was thought that there is a special type of Field in django for dynamic update.
Or, a specific code to run that validates that models Match and Month having a dependency.

I also thought that this is a very common need for any django developer and im planning to have more models in my site that are going to be depended on each other.

Im using PostGreSQL for my project if its relevant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't. You introduce a lot of data duplication here. It turns out that synchronizing data, even on the same database, is a problem that is more complex than one expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do *not* keep the number of matches in the `Month` model. You here introduce *data duplication* and it turns out that keeping data synchronized, even on the same database, is a much harder problem that what it appears to be.

I suggest that you add a [**`ForeignKey`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to your `Match` model. This guarantees *referential integrity*: the database will ensure that it points to a valid `Month` object. Furthermore you then work with `Month` objects, which thus adds a "semantical layer"., and the code no  longer has a ["*primitive obsession*" code smell [refactoring-guru]](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

```
class Month(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Match(models.Model):
    first_team = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    second_team = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then you can obtain the number of matches in a `Month` with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Month.objects.annotate(
    matches_count=Count('match')
)
```

`Month` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.matches_count` that contains the number of related `Match` objects. If you need this often, you can annotate this in the `objects` manager:

```
class MonthManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        super().get_queryset().annotate(
            matches_count=Count('match')
        )

class Month(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    objects = MonthManager()
```